# Creating pointer Attributes in cocos2d iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game. There are balls that fall from the top of the screen, and the player has to catch them, as the are caught they stack ontop of one another. I have a method that creates each new ball and adds it to an Array that i use to move the sprites. Problem is that the after they collide I need them to stop moving, since the array is called on to move them they all move. And if i try to make them stop they all stop. So I was hoping to create a pointer attribute if ther is such a think, for example "sprite.position"  I need a new attribute that i can check like a boolean. I was hoping to create a attribute like sprite.hasCollided and if it returns YES then the ball should no longer move. Is this possible or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks
Tanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCNodes (and, by inheritence, CCSprites) have a userData property, which is a void*. You can use this to relate a custom object to a cocos2d object. Keep in mind if you use the userData option, you will, in most cases, need to allocate any memory when you create/assign the sprite, and release it when you are done.

```
int* myInt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*myInt = 0;
sprite.userData = myInt;

//some time later, when you are done with the sprite
free(sprite.userData);
```

As an improvement on the userData property, you can do what xuanweng suggests and create a ball object containing various game-related properties for the balls, and assign an instance of this to each of your ball CCSprites using the method above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a ball object. And add the boolean as as part of the object.